# Insert lines from a file inside quotes in the script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code

```
from nsepy import get_history
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd

test = get_history(symbol='LINE',
                   start=date(2014,4,1),
                   end=date(2021,3,31), series='EQ')
print(test.to_csv('LINE.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=True))
```

what I need is, read a file with each line as an input in place of LINE.
I don't know how to insert a line from a file inside quotes. Helping will be very much appreciated.
I was not good with python terms, so I could not get a solution I needed by googling

Comment: Could you give a sample input/output? Did you mean you want to read from a text file with different `symbols` in each line and use the value per line in the `get_history` function to convert to CSV?

Comment: I have a text file with 100 lines where each line is a word. that word should be given instead of LINE in the above code by using a for loop.

Comment: What I did now is I wrote a bash script to insert that line in the place. Thank you

Comment: I've added an answer. Do check if it helps

Answer (score 0):

I've taken a sample text file that gives a list of symbols. Each value is substituted in the loop as every line is read from this file. A new CSV file is generated each time according to the symbol name.

**Sample - symbols.txt**

```
TCS
SBIN
NIFTY
```

**Code**

```
filename = 'symbols.txt'
with open(filename) as file:
    for line in file:
        name = line.strip()
        test = get_history(symbol=name,
                        start=date(2014,4,1),
                        end=date(2021,3,31), series='EQ')
        csvName = name + '.csv'
        print(test.to_csv(csvName, encoding='utf-8', index=True))
```